# How to load root level js file and other static contents in mvc view within an area?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, web-config, asp.net-mvc-areas, static-content

I've a folder structure like below:

[image]

I want to add some contents from the resource folder into my views under TestArea. But its giving a 404 error. I googled for the problem & updated the web.config folder under TestArea-->Views as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

But still the error keeps showing. Here is how I added the files in my view.

```
<script src="~/Resources/dynamsoft.webtwain.initiate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Resources/dynamsoft.webtwain.config.js"></script>
```

In fact I was having similar problem even without using area, but changes in the root web.config file solved my issues in that case. But now nothing working.

Comment: You should be able to add the js file from a folder in your root to a view in area. No need of we config changes. Are you sure you are getting a 404 for the js files ? The name is correct ?

Comment: I'm using Twain web api for scanner integration, may be they are using more than just js file, might be some other contents. I saw them to change the root web.config file in their code sample. I did the same but facing the 404 while using it in area view.

Comment: Without any web.config change, area view is trying to access the file in the link as http://localhost:2028/TestArea/Resources/dynamsoft.webtwain.install.js . But the file actually exist in http://localhost:2028/Resources/dynamsoft.webtwain.install.js . So area view is adding TestArea in resource url.

Comment: can u try <script src="@Url.Content("~/Resources/dynamsoft.webtwain.config.js")"></script>

Comment: I tried almost all the way to add js file including but still not get any solution.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue with the exact same control. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, I surely got a workaround, but can't remember now! I changed my job too, so can't see the code either. Should have posted what did the trick. :(